# What decides packETH's maximum packet generation speed?

Tags: networking, network-programming, packet

I've been using packETH for a while and I have always wondered one thing.

When I set packet generation speed on Gen-b option, I realized packETH doesn't really send packets as set.

I think when I use packETH on a virtual machine, maximum speed tends to decrease.

Even if I set number of packets to send : 40000000 and set packets per second : 4000000, the operation wouldn't be finished in 10 seconds and instead I think packETH tries to send out packets as fast as possible but can't quite reach that speed and decides to send out packets slower and therefore taking longer for the operation to finish.

So, what decides packETH's maximum packet generation/transfer speed?

Does it automatically adjust the maximum speed so that the receiving server can intake all the packets correctly?

Thank you so much in advnace.

Comment: Also, if you guys could recommend me a packet generator that can generate packet at my desired rate regardless of the fact that whether the server on the other side is able to process that amount of packets, it would be great! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've read about packETH and I didn't found anything related to be a multi-threaded package sender, so there should be a problem. What you want is a multithreaded package sender which can receive any amount of packages and send them in parallel. But first, let focus on packETH:

You have tried which configuration?

> In the Auto mode you can choose one of five distribution modes. Except the random mode you can see different timings by choosing different mode. In the random mode the generator tries to be smart :). Beside timing you can also specify the amount of traffic for each stream. In the manual mode you select all of the parameters by hand.

Here is where I've found it: http://packeth.sourceforge.net/packeth/GUI_version.html

Related to a multithreaded sender I would suggest [trafgen](https://www.mankier.com/8/trafgen), let's expose some features:

**This will help you at not worrying about limit**

> Process a number of packets and then exit. If the number of packets is 0, then this is equivalent to infinite packets resp. processing until interrupted. Otherwise, a number given as an unsigned integer will limit processing.

**This will ensure paralelism**

> Specify the number of processes trafgen shall fork(2) off. By default trafgen will start as many processes as CPUs that are online and pin them to each, respectively. Allowed value must be within interval [1,CPUs].

Comment: Thank you so much! I thought I have looked up everything available on the internet about packETH but I guess I have missed some! You saved my life xD

Comment: Happy to help! Can you assign it as the answer? It will may help others :)